# Change parameters and run SELECT access queries using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a couple (3) SELECT queries which are linked to excel files and require regular updates (weekly).

I am trying to create a module in access using VBA that can do two things:

- Update a few parameters to be selected, which I defined as variables that I can update manually: CurrentWeek, RetailWeek, CurrentYear and Current Date
- After the update it would run the queries so I can refresh the data in the excel file.

I have tried a couple things but so far no success, I think the closest I got is:

Private Sub DevicePerformanceDashboard()

```
Dim CurrentWeek, RetailWeek, CurrentYear As Long
Dim CurrentDate As Date
Dim qRP, qPP, qMV As DAO.QueryDef
Dim dbs As DAO.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

CurrentYear = 2018
CurrentWeek = 31
RetailWeek = CurrentWeek - 8
CurrentDate = TimeValue("2018-06-01 00:00:00")


Set qRP = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DPDashboardRetail")
Set qPP = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DPDashboardPricePrediction")
Set qMV = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DPDashboardVolume")

qRP.Parameters("YearNb").Value = CurrentYear
qRP.Parameters("WeekNb").Value = ">" & RetailWeek

qPP.Parameters("WeekNb").Value = ">" & CurrentWeek
qPP.Parameters("PreWeekNb").Value = CurrentWeek
qPP.Parameters("PreYearNb").Value = CurrentYear

qMV.Parameters("VolumeAndValueDate").Value = CurrentDate

DoCmd.OpenQuery "DPDashboardRetail"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "DPDashboardPricePrediction"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "DPDashboardVolume"
```

End Sub

Currently I get an error saying `Object required` but I tried it some other ways and I got different errors at different times.

**UPDATE:** Now the error is at the line:

```
    qRP.Parameters("YearNb").Value = CurrentYear

    Item not found in this collection
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Many errors:

```
Dim CurrentWeek As Long
Dim RetailWeek As Long
Dim CurrentYear As Long
Dim CurrentDate As Date
Dim qRP As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qPP As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qMV As DAO.QueryDef
Dim dbs As DAO.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb

CurrentYear = 2018
CurrentWeek = 31
RetailWeek = CurrentWeek - 8
CurrentDate = DateSerial(2018, 6, 1)

Set qRP = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DPDashboardRetail")
Set qPP = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DPDashboardPricePrediction")
Set qMV = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DPDashboardVolume")

qRP.Parameters("YearNb").Value = CurrentYear
' Cannot do:
' qRP.Parameters("WeekNb").Value = ">" & RetailWeek

' Cannot do:
' qPP.Parameters("WeekNb").Value = ">" & CurrentWeek
qPP.Parameters("PreWeekNb").Value = CurrentWeek
qPP.Parameters("PreYearNb").Value = CurrentYear

qMV.Parameters("VolumeAndValueDate").Value = CurrentDate

qRP.Execute
qPP.Execute
qMV.Execute
```

> Item not found in this collection

This indicates a *missing or misspelled* field/parameter in the SQL.

Comment: Thanks! I believe the ">" is necessary, do you know if is there any other way for doing it?

Comment: It must be incorporated in the SQL.

Comment: You mean running the SQL in the VBA?

Comment: No. Adjust the SQL to have something like `where somefield > [WeekNb]`.

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is a keyword that only should be used with objects, hence the *Object required* error. To assign values to a variable, just `VariableName = SomeValue` is enough, only use `Set variableName = SomeObject` when assigning objects.

Furthermore, `qdf.Parameters` goes with `qdf.Execute` to execute the query. `DoCmd.OpenQuery` goes with `DoCmd.SetParameter` to set parameters.

The parameters collection created by `DoCmd.SetParameter` gets cleared when you use `DoCmd.OpenQuery`, so that requires some restructuring of your code.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub DevicePerformanceDashboard()

    Dim CurrentWeek, RetailWeek, CurrentYear As Long
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    CurrentYear = 2018
    CurrentWeek = 31
    RetailWeek = CurrentWeek - 8
    CurrentDate = TimeValue("2018-06-01 00:00:00")

    DoCmd.SetParameter "YearNb", CurrentYear
    DoCmd.SetParameter "WeekNb", ">" & RetailWeek
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "DPDashboardRetail"        

    DoCmd.SetParameter "WeekNb", ">" & CurrentWeek
    DoCmd.SetParameter "PreWeekNb", CurrentWeek
    DoCmd.SetParameter "PreYearNb", CurrentYear
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "DPDashboardPricePrediction"

    DoCmd.SetParameter "VolumeAndValueDate", CurrentDate                
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "DPDashboardVolume"

End Sub
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Now I get an error at `DoCmd.SetParameter "WeekNb", ">" & RetailWeek`, saying 2431 - The expression you entered contains invalid syntax. So maybe there is an issue with the ">" sign? I will do some more research.

Comment: Well, if that parameter is supposed to be a number, that's invalid, of course. If the parameter is supposed to be a string, you could try using `DoCmd.SetParameter "WeekNb", CStr(">" & RetailWeek)`

Comment: Still the same error, in access design view or SQL I just add >20, for example, but I dont think its being interpreted correctly

Comment: Of course. In SQL view you can use comparison operators, but these can't be passed as parameters. Only values can be passed as parameters, nothing else.